# With python-docx, when I change font properties in a table cell, the whole document acquires that property

Tags: python-docx

I have a table with two columns. I want to underline the text in column 0 and leave it normal in column 1.

However, if I change the style in cells of column 0 to `.style.font.underline = True`, the whole document gets underlined.

Now if in addition I change the style in cells of column 1 to `.style.font.underline = False`, the underline in column 0 disappears.

Here is an example:

```
import docx
from docx import Document
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph

doc = Document()
doc.add_paragraph('Before table')

table = doc.add_table(rows=0, cols=2)
row_cells = table.add_row().cells
row_cells[0].text = "Dog"
row_cells[0].paragraphs[0].style.font.underline = True

row_cells[1].text = "Grey"
# row_cells[1].paragraphs[0].style.font.underline = False

row_cells = table.add_row().cells
row_cells[0].text = "Cat"
row_cells[0].paragraphs[0].style.font.underline = True

row_cells[1].text = "Black"
# row_cells[1].paragraphs[0].style.font.underline = False

doc.add_paragraph('After table')

doc.save(r"table_test.docx")
```

Run this example to see how the whole document gets underlined.

Now uncomment the commented lines,  run again, and you will see that the underline disappears everywhere, including column 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are changing the font on a *style* and that style (probably "Normal") is applied to all the paragraphs in the table.

In general, font characteristics are applied at the `Run` level. This is why you can, for example, have a **bold** word in the middle of a sentence.

```
row_cells = table.add_row().cells
cell = row_cells[0]
# ---each newly-added cell contains a single empty paragraph---
paragraph = cell.paragraphs[0]
run = paragraph.add_run("Dog")
run.underline = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution (inspired by @scanny) is to create two new styles specifically for table cells:

```
import docx
from docx import Document
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE

doc = Document()

styles = doc.styles

# Create hyperlink style
hyperlink_style = styles.add_style('Hyperlink', WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
hyperlink_style.font.underline = True

regcell_style = styles.add_style('Regcell', WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
regcell_style.font.underline = False

doc.add_paragraph('Before table')

table = doc.add_table(rows=0, cols=2)
row_cells = table.add_row().cells
row_cells[0].text = "Dog"
row_cells[0].paragraphs[0].style = hyperlink_style
row_cells[1].text = "Grey"
row_cells[1].paragraphs[0].style = regcell_style

row_cells = table.add_row().cells
row_cells[0].text = "Cat"
row_cells[0].paragraphs[0].style = hyperlink_style

row_cells[1].text = "Black"
row_cells[1].paragraphs[0].style = regcell_style


doc.add_paragraph('After table')

doc.save(r"table_test.docx")
```